# PhantomJS renders partial SVG output from d3

Tags: d3.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to render SVG images at the back-end using `d3` on `PhantomJS`. `PhantomJS` only returns a portion of the SVG (just the header).

**What I've tried so far**:

1. I ran the same script in the browser console and noticed that if I try to do `alert(d3.select("#pieChart").html())` (see code below) immediately after running `svgDrawer`, it shows the exact partial SVG. But then the pie gets rendered on to the HTML, and running `alert(d3.select("#pieChart").html())` again gives me the complete SVG.
2. Thinking that the rendering wasn't complete while I returned the value in PhantomJS, I split my method into two - `svgDrawer` and `svgGrabber`. But even then, `svgGrabber` returns partial SVG data when called from PhantomJS. Note that the same two methods, run serially in browser console, now shows the complete SVG

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my boilerplate HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="d3pie.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="pieChart"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'file://' + fs.absolute('./d3.html');

var svgDrawer = function() {
    var pie = new d3pie("pieChart", {
        "header": {
            "title": {
                "text": "My pieChart"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "content": [
                {
                    "label": "slice 1",
                    "value": 60.9,
                    "color": "#8fbc8f"
                },
                {
                    "label": "slice 2",
                    "value": 8.7,
                    "color": "#dadde0"
                },
                {
                    "label": "slice 3",
                    "value": 30.4,
                    "color": "#c1d82f"
                }
            ]
        }
    })
};

var svgGrabber = function() {
    return d3.select("#pieChart").html()
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
   page.evaluate(svgDrawer)
   console.log(page.evaluate(svgGrabber));
   phantom.exit();
});
```

and here is the command I use to generate the final SVG:

```
phantomjs d3_pie.js > d3_pie.svg
```

Comment: Have you tried to asynchronize it? Ex: `page.evaluate(svgDrawer); setTimeout(function(){ console.log(page.evaluate(svgGrabber)); phantom.exit(); }, 0);`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, tried that already and that worked. Forgot to update here :D I was going to answer myself, but if you would post this as an answer, I could mark that as accepted. Thanks.